# Is is possible completely custom default ActionBar style?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles

In my activity, I use default ActionBar

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">` and `getSupportActionBar()`

How can I custom the style of this ActionBar?

1. Change ActionBar color and title color
2. Align title to center
3. Add more top padding to ActionBar

For the color, I tried these two style, but it also change color of whole Activity, I just want to change ActionBar

```
<item name="colorPrimary"></item>
<item name="android:textColorPrimary"></item>
```

I alo tried actionBarStyle, but it is not working

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/darkgray</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/gold</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/gold</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/darkgray</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/gray</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to include the `Toolbar` in your layout and use the `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` theme for your Activity :

Layout :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/yourColor">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/yourColor"
        android:text="yourTitle" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Manifest :

```
<activity
    android:name="yourActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />
```